# Would then base react with water?

Tags: acid-base, nuclear-chemistry

Imagine you fill a tank with undecayed neutrons and water .Now neutrons will decay into proton and electrons. Assume that the wall of the container is so thick that it doesn't allow the protons to pass while allow beta rays to pass. The water will now have h + ions and they will make h3o + ions in water that is water will become acidic. Will now 
1. A metal having normal reactivity will give H2 gas
2. NAOH react with solution to give water

Answer (score 1):

Your proton-charged water will not last long enough to react selectivy with any electropositive metal or a base that you add.  Electrostatic forces are powerful.  The excess protons will grab electrons, generating ions that themselves grab other electrons, until eventually the beta particle electrons that were emitted to begin with get consumed to rebalance the charges.  You might get some unpredicted chemical reactions but no lingering excess charge.